# Replace code for rich:suggestionbox with rich:autocomplete

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am working on richfaces migration from 3.3 to 4.2. I am stuck with the replacement of rich:suggestionbox tag with rich:autocomplete tag.

Richfaces 3.3 code,

```
<rich:suggestionbox for="officerSrch" minChars="2" nothingLabel="No managers found"
                                suggestionAction="#{batchProcessor.searchOfficers}" fetchValue=""
                                var="o" eventsQueue="officerQueue"
                                height="270" width="480">   
                    <a4j:support event="onselect" action="#{accountLookupAction.add(o)}" reRender="params"/>                    
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Employee ID"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{o.employeeId}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="First Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{o.firstName}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Last Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{o.lastName}"/>
                    </h:column>
                </rich:suggestionbox>
```

Can anyone please guide me to convert the above code to richfaces 4?

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces 4.2.0 Final version rich:autocomplete is not working properly. As per the Jboss developer suggestion I have upgraded the version from 4.2.0.Final to 4.5.13.Final.

You can refer the following link, https://developer.jboss.org/thread/267610

I have found the solution to this issue. It will be help to resolve someone facing the same issue. Here is y solution,

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="2" autofill="false" selectFirst="false" 
                    autocompleteMethod="#{batchProcessor.searchOfficers}" id="officerSrch" layout="table" fetchValue="#{o.employeeId}"
                    value="#{accountLookupAction.empId}" var="o" eventsQueue="officerQueue" height="270" width="480">   
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Employee ID"/>
                        </f:facet>               
                        <h:outputText value="#{o.employeeId}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="First Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{o.firstName}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Last Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{o.lastName}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" listener="#{accountLookupAction.addOfficer()}" render="params"/>
                </rich:autocomplete>
```

1. Header value is not supported in rich:aotocomplete.
2. fetchValue attribute cannot be empty you should assign the value that you
   wanted to use in the action class.
3. You cannot assign or pass any object through rich:autocomplete. It is currently supports only String value.